# Conditional Rendering in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I am trying to conditionally render a field in a form based on a value in that form. I've created an example here:

https://svelte.dev/repl/54917929b89646339a9c7498c13f7b38?version=3.17.3

The gist of the question is that I'm creating a control and using its `slot` which contains some conditional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is not reactive in Svelte, meaning changes in value are not tracked. You need something reactive, for the view to react.

What you can do is put a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store) in the context.

For example, in `App.svelte`:

```js
    import { setContext } from 'svelte'
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
    let data = writable({});
    setContext("data", data);
```

Then, deeper in the child component (notice the `$` prefix to read / write the store value in the template):

```js
  let data = getContext("data");

  const handleInput = event => {

    // NOTE the dollar prefix to access the value
    $data[fieldName] =
      event.target.type === "checkbox"
        ? event.target.checked
        : event.target.value;
  };
```

[REPL using store in context](https://svelte.dev/repl/fac3f6470d7f4bed81223364b964cf25?version=3.17.3)

Another way would be simply to use [two way binding](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property).

In `App.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    // ...
    let data = {};
</script>

<Form submit={submit}>
    <FormField bind:data ... />
    {#if data.type && data.type === 'Local'}
        <FormField bind:data ... />
    {/if}
</Form>
```

And in your `FormField.svelte`:

```js
    export let data
```

[REPL using binding](https://svelte.dev/repl/e36bd405dd6b4ab1869ac12d499e052e?version=3.17.3)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Works like a charm. Do you think this example would be something for the "Examples" in the documentation?